# Build failure with CUDA, clang unknown warning option

Tags: tensorflow, clang, llvm-clang

I am building TensorFlow with bazel, CUDA supported, on AWS GPU instance. I got:

```
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-invalid-partial-specialization'
```

Build options:

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures
```

Detailed error message:

```
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/ad1e09741bb4109fbc70ef8216b59ee2/external/boringssl/BUILD:91:1: C++ compilation of rule '@boringssl//:crypto' failed: clang failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/ad1e09741bb4109fbc70ef8216b59ee2/execroot/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    CLANG_CUDA_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/clang \
    COMPUTECPP_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/computecpp \
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/cuda \
    CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 \
    HOST_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ \
    HOST_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages \
    TF_CUDA_CLANG=1 \
    TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=3.5,5.2 \
    TF_CUDA_VERSION=8.0 \
    TF_CUDNN_VERSION='' \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=1 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL=1 \
  /usr/bin/clang '-march=native' -MD -MF bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/external/boringssl/src/crypto/sha/sha512.pic.d -iquote external/boringssl -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/boringssl -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/boringssl/src/include -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/boringssl/src/include -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wno-invalid-partial-specialization -fno-omit-frame-pointer -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -g0 -O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack '-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700' -Wall -Werror '-Wformat=2' -Wsign-compare -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -fno-common '-std=c11' -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -c external/boringssl/src/crypto/sha/sha512.c -o bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/external/boringssl/src/crypto/sha/sha512.pic.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-invalid-partial-specialization' [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

Comment: which clang version are you using?

Comment: Same issue for me. I am using clang with version `3.8.0-2ubuntu4`